# I'm stepping down from moderation duties, and here's why

Tags: discussion

I simply do not have the amount of time to give, that I think this site deserves.  While my family continues to grow, "free time" has become a thing of the past.  My responsibilities at work have also grown, leaving me no downtime there either (not that I should have been moderating on the job anyway).

[BMitch](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/2196/bmitch), [ChrisF](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/194/chrisf), and [Niall C](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/22/niall-c), should have no problem handling the site without me. However, if they decide to elect a replacement, here are a few folks I think you should consider.

- [ThreePhaseEel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/27099/threephaseeel)
- [The Evil Greebo](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/3525/the-evil-greebo)
- [Daniel Griscom](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/27773/daniel-griscom)
- [mmathis](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/56531/mmathis)
- [Tyson](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/53243/tyson)
- [fixer1234](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/28390/fixer1234)

All of these folks would make fantastic moderators.  They're all already quite active in keeping the site clean for us all, by constantly trudging through the review queues, and flagging bad content.

I very much enjoyed my time as moderator, through the good times and the bad.  And I thank you all for giving me the opportunity to be a moderator, and putting up with my stubbornness.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for not only stepping up as a moderator but also being a huge contributor to the site. If life ever gives you some of that free time again, I hope to see you back around the site.

Comment: I'd like to add my thanks and best wishes too. We're sad to see you go but it's best to go on your own terms rather than someone else's.

Comment: I want to upvote this but you nominated me and that is unforgivable! ;)

Comment: Say it ain't so... I've learned so much from you (and argued a bit too). We need you bro.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it NFPA offers read-only versions of their code books online, so I'm no longer needed.  Go sign up for a free NFPA account, and start reading ;)